# Matlab 2-D sorting

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab script which records a person speaking a phone number then finds where each number is spoken. Basically, I have the index within the main file where a smaller file is spoken; sometimes the smaller file can be found twice.

I have the indexes all the locations of '0', say they are 200 and 350. Now I find the indexes of '1', say 100 and 250. How can I reconstruct the phone number based on these indexes? The final answer should be '1010'. Can I have an array of tuples or something like:

```
x(1)=(200,0)
x(2)=(350,0)
x(3)=(100,1)
x(4)=(250,1)
```

Then sort them by their first element? If that is possible, I do not know the correct syntax. I hope this makes sense. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Store X as a matrix like this:

```
 X=[ [200 0]
 [350 0]
 [100 1]
 [250 1]]
```

Then sort it via [sortrows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html)

```
>>sortrows(X)

ans =

   100     1
   200     0
   250     1
   350     0
```